# Remove PNG Background to have multiple layers of PNG that can be hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm making some sort of interactive map for a roleplaying game I have, where I want to be able to hover a country and it can scale up a bit and have a hover effect and so you can be able to click on it and it will give you main info of the country and stuff. Now the issue comes that I'm trying to check if there is a way to have multiple PNG layered up on HTML, CSS, JS and avoid having the transparent background of the top layer hover only that specific one. I'm trying to check if there is a way for the code to detect only the colored area of the img or if this is not possible.

I've tried layering with the z-index, but that doesn't really resolve the issue.

Comment: Ive done something similar to this before using **svg paths**.  The end result allowed single countries to be hovered over, context to be displayed, and was clickable.

Comment: Do you have a example perhaps so I can check how you did it?

Comment: Here you have a nice example hovering map with svg https://codepen.io/colinrei/pen/MWeXgLz , don´t use PNG

Comment: We actually used the plugin `jquery.maphilight`. There are some links to it, but the official link I found for it no longer works.  Essentially you create the map element and inside have areas set to poly shape and add the coordinates.

Comment: Isn't that part of jquery already? I was trying to find a link to path it to my project or a direct link but no luck

Comment: I do not know if this is part of the jquery library (highly doubt it would be).  Im sure there are other plugins that do this same thing though.  The link from @marcos.efrem is a good example of the svg path implementation.